# Django 2.0 testing login required for password change failing with syntax error

Tags: python, django

I am working through the tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/beginners-guide/1.11/ from Vitor Freitas.

I am using Django 2.0.7 for this task. I know that the tutorial was written for 1.11 and I have been fixing any challenges that have come up during the process. Currently I am having issues with one test that is failing to run due to this error

> ```
> ====================================================================== ERROR: accounts.tests.test_view_password_change
> ```
>
> (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError: Failed to import test module:
>   accounts.tests.test_view_password_change Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in
>   _find_test_path
>       module = self._get_module_from_name(name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in
>   _get_module_from_name
>       **import**(name)   File "/home/lance/dev/proj/accounts/tests/test_view_password_change.py",
>   line 44
>       self.assertRedirects(response, f'{login_url}?next={url}')

The test code is question looks like this

```
class PasswordChangeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        username = 'john'
        password = 'secret123'
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email='john@doe.com', password=password)
        url = reverse('password_change')
        self.client.login(username=username, password=password)
        self.response = self.client.get(url)


class LoginRequiredPasswordChangeTests(TestCase):
    def test_redirection(self):
        url = reverse('password_change')
        login_url = reverse('login')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertRedirects(response, f'{login_url}?next={url}')
```

The invalid syntax seems to come from the last line

> self.assertRedirects(response, f'{login_url}?next={url}')

Can someone help me out as to why this is invalid?
As I understand it the test is looking for the pattern that is listed in the single quotes and I have tested that it is there.

I can't understand why the single quotes is incorrect.

Comment: f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. They are a syntax error in earlier versions. Might that be your problem?

Comment: I just checked and I believe that you are correct. Can you create an answer so I can credit you with it?

Comment: Answer created as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f`-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. They are a syntax error in earlier versions. Might that be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`F string literals`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) is implemented **`Python 3.6`** onwards. So make sure you are using `Python 3.6+`.

You can also use `str.format()` method as,
**`self.assertRedirects(response, '{}?next={}'.format(login_url, url))`**

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip. I will try your solution to change the test URL. I realised my virtualenv was on 3.5 and updated to 3.6